# How to set java object attribute like the way in javascript

Tags: java

All:

I have a data model object in Java like:

```
class Model {
    String name;
    String email;
}
```

What I want to do is dynamically determine what attribute I want to set by using a variable like in Javascript object;

```
String field = "name";

// This is what I try to achieve, not the real code.
New Model().field = "according content";
or 
New Model()[field] = "according content";
```

Thanks

Comment: you could use reflection

Comment: @ScaryWombat Thanks for reply. Could you just give out a simple example for my case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could reflection as in this [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/fieldValues.html)

In this example they have

```
   public long chapters = 0;
```

and can get/set it as

```
    Field chap = c.getDeclaredField("chapters");
    out.format(fmt, "before", "chapters", book.chapters);
    chap.setLong(book, 12);
    out.format(fmt, "after", "chapters", chap.getLong(book));
```